# Sending a button in a putExtra - Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-button

I have 2 activities with me - `Activity1` and `Activity2`.

I have 2 buttons in `Activity1':

**Button 1:**

```
<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/button1"
  android:layout_width="45dp"
  android:layout_height="47dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="600dp"
  android:backgroundTint="#131D47"
  android:background="@drawable/notes_add"
  android:layout_marginStart="163dp"
  android:onClick="open3Buttons"/>
```

**Button 2:**

```
<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/button2"
  android:layout_width="45dp"
  android:layout_height="47dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="600dp"
  android:backgroundTint="#131D47"
  android:background="@drawable/notes_add"
  android:layout_marginStart="163dp"
  android:onClick="open3Buttons"/>
```

**Activity 2 code:**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#131D47"
        android:fontFamily="@font/notosanskr_bold"/>
```

In `Activity1`, when a person presses the first button, in `Activity2`, it should show that you pressed the first button. When a person presses the second button, it should show that you pressed the second button.

I know you do this from an Intent and putExtra(), but I am not sure about a button. Thank you and it would be nice if you could also tell me what if the button was a RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity1:

```
fun open3Buttons(v: View) {
    val intent = Intent(this, Activity2::class.java)
    val id = v.id
    when(id) {
        R.id.button1 -> intent.putExtra("myKey", "button1 click")
        R.id.button2 -> intent.putExtra("myKey", "button2 click")
    }
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

In your Acttivity2 onCreate():

```
val extras = intent?.extras
extras?.let {
    txt.text = extras.get("myKey")
}
```

Comment: It is tagged in java please consider changing your answer to java.

Comment: I am writing my answer in java, not kotlin, but it's okay, I can figure it out.